# Recommended TextMate Bundles for Ruby on Rails Development

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, textmate, textmatebundles

Can you guys please recommend few textmate bundles that would be  helpful while developing ruby on rails applications

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Kevin Faustino put together a fairly recent list (May 2010) of his favorite Textmate bundles.](http://adventuresincoding.com/2010/05/10-textmate-bundlesplugins-to-boost-your-ruby-on-rails-development-productivity/) This list got me started on improving my productivity with Textmate and searching the web for Textmate bundles that fit my personal needs.

Answer (score 2):

The [Ruby on Rails bundle](http://github.com/drnic/ruby-on-rails-tmbundle), obvi. The [jQuery bundle](http://github.com/kswedberg/jquery-tmbundle) is also cool if you happen to be using Rails with jQuery.